# How to keep flash when redirecting to the login page

Tags: java, playframework

I'm implementing an email mechanism in Play:

1. User gets an email with a validation link
2. Clicks on it, gets to a controller that saves the "validated" bit on the user model, then redirects him to another page.
3. Before redirecting, that last page puts a message into the `flash` object ... to be displayed later in whatever page the user ends up at, via javascript. The message says "thanks for validating your email".
4. The target page has @With(Secure.class), so if the user is not authenticated I reach the Secure.login() method.

Now, at this point, I find that `flash` does not contain the message I just put in there before the redirection. What is the correct way to use flash in a way that survives this redirect?

Comment: When redirecting the only thing that survives is the session data; is your flash object stored in session?

Comment: @Viruzzo - flash is the Play object that survives between requests. I am now trying to copy the `Secure` class, and add `flash.keep();` after `if(!session.contains("username")) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
public class OurSecure extends Controller {

  @Before(unless={"login", "authenticate", "logout"})
  static void checkAccess() throws Throwable {
    // Authent
    if(!session.contains("username")) {

        // __ my modification __ :
        flash.keep(); 


        flash.put("url", "GET".equals(request.method) ? request.url : "/");
        // seems a good default
        login();
    }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm... well, its a slightly different use case, but thats the way how I remember which page the user wanted to access when he got redirected to the login page, so I can redirect him back there after successful authentication. maybe it helps

```
@Before(only = "authenticate")
public static void preserveUrl()
{
    String url = request.params.get("url");
    if(
            "authenticate".equals(request.actionMethod) &&
            url != null &&
            !url.toLowerCase().contains("http") &&
            !url.toLowerCase().contains("ftp")
      )
    {
        flash.put("url", url);
    }
}

static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    if(username == null || password == null)
        return false;
    String passwordHash = Codec.hexMD5(password.trim());
    Member m = Member.findByEmailAddressPasswordHashAndStatus(username, passwordHash, Member.STATUS.ACTIVE);
    return m != null;
}
```